# Calculating an exact orthogonal modal matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I can calculate the modal matrix of a matrix **A** using the command `JordanDecomposition[A][[1]]`, and a decimal approximation of the orthogonal (or normalised) modal matrix using `JordanDecomposition[N[A]][[1]]` but I would like to know how to calculate the answer in an exact form.

The example I'm using is `A = {{1, 1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2, 1}}` where using the method above I get a orthogonal modal matrix of

```
{{0.57735, -0.57735, 0.57735}, {-0.57735, 0.211325, 0.788675}, {0.57735, 0.788675, 0.211325}}
```

which results in, for $ y = x^T . A . x $

```
{{y1}, {y2}, {y3}} == {{0.57735 x1 - 0.57735 x2 + 
0.57735 x3}, {-0.57735 x1 + 0.211325 x2 + 
0.788675 x3}, {0.57735 x1 + 0.788675 x2 + 0.211325 x3}}
```

rather than the exact form:
$$ y_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} x_1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} x_2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} x_3 $$
$$ y_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x_2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x_3 $$
$$ y_3 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} x_1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} x_2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} x_3 $$

How can I get this exact form using Mathematica commands?

Answer (score 3):

Works nicely:

```
Orthogonalize[First[JordanDecomposition[{{1, 1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2, 1}}]]]
```

> ```
>    {{1/Sqrt[3], -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]},
>     {-1/Sqrt[2], 0, 1/Sqrt[2]},
>     {1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3], 1/Sqrt[6]}}
> ```